# Rhombus with letters - Java

Tags: java

I am new to programming and started with learning c# and now java. I came across a task creating a rhombus where the user inputs the height (odd numbers only) and the char for the rhombus.
I created a for loop for the height and another loop for the characters. Here is my output:

```
h: 7
c: k
      k
     jkj
    ijkji
   hijkjih
  ghijkjihg
```

But I want the output to be:

```
h: 7
c: k
  
   k 
  jkj 
 ijkji 
hijkjih
 ijkji 
  jkj 
   k
```

How can I develop my logic to apply it to my code.
Here is my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("h: ");
int h = in.nextInt();
System.out.print("c: ");
char c = in.next().charAt(0);

if(h%2==0){
    System.out.println("Invalid number!");
    return;
}

int count = 1;
int space = 1;

for (int i = 2; i < h; i++)
{
    for (int spc = h - space; spc > 0; spc--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    if (i < h)
    {
        space++;
    }
    else {
        space--;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(c);
        if (j < count/2)
        {
            c++;
        }
        else {
            c--;
        }
    }
    if (i < h)
    {
        count = count + 2;
    }
    else {
        count = count - 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I translated Leerzeichen to space (we use only English on this site)

Comment: Thank you - I am sorry, I forgot to adapt this part of the code for stackoverflow

Comment: I don't understand about the height value though. Care to explain?

Comment: it seems to me that you have an error in your desired output. Shouldn't the last line be `k` instead of `j`?

Comment: The height value is tricky. The intention is to determine the height of the rhombus. So for instance if the user inputs 7 then it should display 7 rows but in my case it outputs five rows.
I see I made a mistake here. The expected output for a height of 7 and the char k should be:

      k
     jkj
    ijkji
   hijkjih
    ijkji
     jkj
      k

Comment: I edited it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code contains the following flaws:

- `count` and `space` variables depend on the values of `i` and `h`, which makes it very hard to keep track of and understand. You should avoid hidden dependencies in your code in general
- you change the value of `c` all the time. It makes it very hard to keep track of. You should never change its value
- your function is too big
- strange values like `i = 2`, `count/2`, incrementing by `2`
- incorrect conditions

You have one loop which increments `i`. What you need is a second loop which decrements the value of `i`. And you should also use the same approach for printing of the characters (2 loops for both sides). Let me show you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // load parameters
    System.out.print("h: ");
    int h = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("c: ");
    char c = in.next().charAt(0);

    // validate parameters
    if (h % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number!");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= h/2; i++) {
        printSpaces((h+1) / 2 - i - 1);
        printLine(c, i);
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i = h/2-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printSpaces((h+1) / 2 - i - 1);
        printLine(c, i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static void printLine(char character, int sideWidth) {
    for (int j = sideWidth; j >= 0; j--)
        System.out.print((char) (character - j));
    for (int j = 1; j <= sideWidth; j++)
        System.out.print((char) (character - j));
}

private static void printSpaces(int numberOfSpaces) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

which gives you the desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the analysis. I had a lot of code smells in my logic. Your code looks very clean and makes sense to me. It also works fine after testing it.

Comment: @linuxman as a homework for you, try to improve my code by getting rid of the code duplication. Hint: create a list to which you add values `[0, 1, 2, …, h, …, 2, 1, 0]` and iterate over it

Comment: After creating the list and adding values to it, I iterated over it using a foreach loop. I am not sure how to replace the for loops with one loop, because one loop is incrementing up and the other one is incrementing down.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Rhombusstar
{
    
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
             
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter N : ");
    int n=sc.nextInt();  
              System.out.print("Enter Symbol : ");
    
              char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
 
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
               {
            for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
                
                        {
                               System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                       for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                
                        {
                               System.out.print(c);
                        }
                   
                            System.out.println();
                       
               }             
 
 
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I am afraid your solution is not what I have been looking for. In your example the output would display whatever char the user enters n-times on each row for n rows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).